# Why does an ellipsis break substr_replace?

Tags: php, character-encoding

If I use `substr_replace()` like so...

```
echo substr_replace('Replace: foo', 'bar', 9, 3);
// Echoes 'Replace:bar'
```

... it works fine, but if change *just* the colon for an ellipsis (not changing the start position) I get...

```
echo substr_replace('Replace… foo', 'bar', 9, 3);
// Echoes 'Replace��baroo'
```

However, if I change the start position it works:

```
 echo substr_replace('Replace… foo', 'bar', 11, 3);
// Echoes 'Replace… bar'
```

Does `substr_replace()` consider an ellipsis to be three separate characters for offsetting purposes? Is it an encoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much hair pulling I found the answer: **`substr_replace` is not multibyte (utf-8) compatible.**

As there's no `mb_substr_replace()` here's a work around that would be equivalent to the example above:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$text = 'Replace… foo';
$start = 9;
$length = 3;
echo mb_substr($text, 0, $start) . $foo . mb_substr($text, $start, $start+$length);
```

More details on the solution can be found in the [PHP Manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#94220)